# I cannot load my website. Instead I get the wordpress installation process page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system, spip

I hosted a wordpress website then I decided to change it and use spip instead. Now when I try to load the website on my laptop I get the wordpress installation process.

It seems to work fine when I load the website on my phone.

Comment: You need to set the right configurations on the config file  and check for the database. Maybe your phone is under cache..erase your cache on your phone .

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your Database ? or did you change / delete your database ? 
if you change host or website you need to upload old Database and do db-replace of urls

Comment: I deleted the wordpress database and it seemed to work at first but now I am back to square one.